# Email spam from thin client company?

Tags: discussion

I've recently received an email which smells a little spammy to me, but I'm uncertain.  Has anybody else received possible spam recently starting something like "I got to know your profile from superuser.com answers you have made"?

> I got to know your profile from superuser.com answers you have made . I have gone through your blog also and its very good . I am working as a software engineer in a thin client company . I would like to be in touch with you . I always like the person who are more interested in latest technologies growth .

Comment: Does the mail say anything else?

Comment: No because most of us don't post our real email as plain text in a world-accessible page. You are really asking for trouble doing that, even if _this_ one is not spam, the next one will be. I'm surprised this is the first time you notice, I guess gmail's SPAM filters are catching most of it.

Comment: @terdon: my email addresses have been public for over twenty years and I've never had any trouble. :-)  I'm really just curious as to whether someone is targeting Super User (or Stack Exchange) in particular.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: the full body, except for greeting and regards, has now been edited into the question.

Comment: Looks like a weak attempt at networking, not outright spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any systematic spamming going on like that.

I also have my email address publicly readable in my profile. I've also received a number of emails from users of the website. If there was any spam, then it probably landed in my spam folder.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't strange at all that you received such emails:

[image]

> A picture says more than thousand words.

Comment: Doesn't mean the people using the address are spammers. I've had people thank me and one even offered to buy content from me for his publication.

Comment: Yeah, but if he obfuscates the email then we would be sure if it's a spammer or a human ;). Also, I'm not saying is a spammer, I'm pointing out why he received such mail.

Answer (score 3):

I get this on a semi-regular basis from Stack Overflow. For a while, I removed my contact information from my profile to limit the amount of noise I received. Now that I'm an employee I'm actually paid to receive it, some of it is actually useful.

Some folks want to round out their online footprint through their tracked relationships (Twitter, Linkedin, etc) - so they seek out people that seem (1) likely to have connections and (2) interesting, withing their fields of endeavor -- for more or less modern day 'pen pals.' and follower / presence 'piggy backing'.

I wouldn't read too much into it.